# Iterating Through Pandas Dataframe Dict, and Outputting The Same Row From All of Them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I creating a DataFrame from an excel file, and am attempting to take the data from the same row on several of the separate sheets.

I can take it from a single sheet by doing the following

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\User\SomeFile.xlsx',sheet_name='Some Sheet') #Designate a single sheet 
print(df.iloc[9])#print just row 9 of the sheet
```

Which then prints/grabs the row I desire.

However, when looping through all the sheets by using

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\User\SomeFile.xlsx',sheet_name=None) #select all sheets
print(df.iloc[9])
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

I'm guessing there is a different approach to iterating 'iloc' through a dict and am curious as to what workarounds there are? Thank you!

Comment: to select all the sheets you would set sheet_name = [list, of, sheets]

Comment: If you read in multiple sheets, you get a dict of dataframes, not a single dataframe. You say "when looping through all the sheets by using..." but the code you show doesn't have a loop; you can access dictionary items with `my_dict.items():` for example, `for k, v in df: print(v.iloc[9])`

Answer (score 0):

So the solution I found for this is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\User\SomeFile.xlsx',sheet_name=None)

for x in df:
    for y in df[x]:
        print((df[x][y]).iloc[9])
```

This printed the ninth row for each sheet as I was hoping it would